# Android Application related to location finder

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have an assignment which includes creating an Android App.

This App should be able to detect any mobile phone in the near by area using the same app by any means, that is network, wifi or GPS.

How can this be made possible? What would be the code and permission required exactly? Are there any given tutorials I could follow to understand this thing? Can I use Google Map in the App to show the detected mobiles in the near by area?

Comment: You don't seem to understand locations detection works.  Location finding features like GPS work by figuring out where they are from satellites.  They do not broadcast their location.  There's no way to use it to find out other devices. You can use it to find your own location and then send that out to a server, or you can use peer to peer like wifi direct to send it to another device nearby.  But you can't use GPS to find a different piece of hardware.

Comment: You would need a "server side" implementation .. so that the app reports location to the server ... and then sees what has been reported within some delta distance.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make your app which sends your Location to the server and save the info with device ID and location there.

2.) From your server send the location of your app to your device and let the details retrieved from server locate your device(eg, on maps).

3.) Now, for multiple devices scenario all the devices with your app sends their location to server individually and then from server, you need to send the cumulative list of data back to each of the device requesting it.

4.) Now you have got all the location data(say address or latitude, longitude or GeoPoint etc.,.) of near by devices. you can just show that on Google Maps.

For reference you need [GOOGLE MAPS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

[Location Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Also, check this Giude for [Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

Then add [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)